# Удаление скобок из строки

Tags: c++, строки

Есть задача: дана строка и нужно найти самый внутренний фрагмент в скобках и вырезать его. И так нужно делать, пока не останется скобок. Полученные фрагменты и остаток строки вывести на экран

```
void cut(char b[])
{
    int count = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    while (b)
    {
        if (b[i] == '(')
        {
            count++;
            i++;
            while (count || b[i] == '(')
            {
                if (b[i] == '(')
                {
                    count++;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                if (b[i] == ')')
                {
                    count--;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                    i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Я все не могу понять по какому принципу это нужно сделать. 
Написал функцию нахождения скобок, а как дальше не знаю.

Comment: Немного не понятно, что происходит с вырезанными фрагментами. Их надо вывести - или же они просто отбрасываются? Во втором случае задача сводится к простому "вырезать все, что не в скобках".

Comment: Полученные фрагменты и остаток строки вывести на экран. Я там не дописал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю следующий алгоритм вам нужен:

1. Идем по строке и ищем последнюю `(` , запоминаем ее номер n1
2. Дальше находим первую `)`(начинать искать ее надо после символа с номером n1) , запоминаем ее номер n2
3. Теперь из исходной строки выводим на экран фрагмент, состоящий из символов с n1 по n2. (может сохраняем его, если нужно)
4. Удаляем из исходной строки фрагмент начиная с n1 по n2.
5. Повторяем пункты 1-4 пока в строке есть `(`.
6. Если скобок нет, то выводим остаток исходной строки.

Данный алгоритм подразумевает, что исходная строка задана корректно (то есть количество `(` и `)` совпадает  и нет чего вроде `)dd)dd)(fff(ff)` )
И еще: я так понимаю у вас строка вида `ffa(dd(gg(rr)hh)ucvu)mm`

Comment: А почему для поиска первой закрывающей скобки не получается воспользоваться циклом?

`for (j = start; b[j] != ')'; j++)
   end = j++;`

А приходится условием (if): `if (b[i] == ')')
  {
   end = i;
   break;
  }` 
start это n1, а end это n2

Comment: @zof используя `j++` вы дополнительно увеличиваете `j` и перескакиваете через скобку. Пишите `end=j+1`

Comment: А почему? Цикл ведь доходит до элемента перед скобкой и останавливается. Я так думал, вот и сразу увеличивал на 1.

Comment: @zof в цикле каждый раз `j` увеличивается на 1. Запись `end=j++` равносильна `end=j; j=j+1; ` вы дополнительно увеличиваете счетчик, причем используя постфиксную запись делаете `end` равным `j` а не на 1 больше `j` . Операция `j++` не просто возвращает `j` она увеличивает его на 1.
Может, вы хотели как то так `for (j = start; b[j] != ')'; ) end = ++j;`

Comment: Алгоритм будет работать неправильно на строке вроде `1(2(3)4)5(6)7`

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

pair<string, string> cut(const string& str) {
    string cut, rem = str;

    auto most_nested = rem.end(); size_t depth = 0, max_depth = 0;
    for (auto it = rem.begin(); it != rem.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it == ')') depth--;
        if (*it == '(') {
            depth++;
            if (depth > max_depth) {
                most_nested = it;
                max_depth = depth;
            }
        }
    }

    if (most_nested != rem.end()) {
        auto b = most_nested;
        auto e = find(b, rem.end(), ')');

        copy(b+1, e, back_inserter(cut));
        rem.erase(b, e+1);
    }

    return make_pair(cut, rem);
}

int main()
{
    string str = "1(2(3(4)5)6)(7)8";

    pair<string, string> curr("", str);
    while (!(curr = cut(curr.second)).first.empty())
        cout << "cut: " << curr.first << ", "
             << "reminder: " << curr.second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Неправильно. Всегда ищет самый правый, но ведь он же не обязательно самый вложенный фрагмент. Например, в: `1(2(3)4)5(6)7` сначала найдет 6, а не 3.

Comment: @avp Принимается. Иногда задачи сложнее, чем кажутся на первый взгляд. Исправил.

Comment: ОК. Теперь плюсанул.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void delsc(ostream& o, char* s, char a, char b){
   char* t = s;
   char* p = s, *i;

   while(*s){
      if(*s == a)
          p = s;
      else if(*s == b){
          if(p != s){
             i = p;

             ++s;
             while(i != s)
                 o << *i++;
             o << endl;

             while((*p = *s) != '\0'){
                 ++p;
                 ++s;
             }

             s = t;
             continue;
         }
     }
     ++s;
   }
   o << t << endl;
}


int main(void){
   char s1[] = "1(2(3)4)5";
   delsc(cout, s1, '(', ')');

   cout << endl << endl;

   char s2[] = "(1(2(3(XYZ))))(A(B(C)))";
   delsc(cout, s2, '(', ')');
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Все очень просто. Вводишь переменную int count. Считаешь количество скобок если count%2!=0, тогда удаляешь все символы которые идут после скобки (то есть скобка открылась) если count%2==0 то отображаешь символы (то есть скобка закрылась). Думаю написать такое тебе самому не составит труда.

Comment: Попробуйте проверить ваш алгоритм вот на этом примере: `1(2(3)4)5`